# Как одинаково расположить картинку на 2-ух кнопках?

Tags: c#, wpf

В общем, есть такая панелька:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<WrapPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <Button Command="{Binding OkCommand}" >
        <Button.ToolTip>Ок</Button.ToolTip>
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="../Icons/Accept.png" Height="30" Width="30"/>
                <Label >Ок</Label>
            </StackPanel>

        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
    <Button Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" >
        <Button.ToolTip>Отмена</Button.ToolTip>
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="../Icons/Cancel.png" Height="30" Width="30"/>
                <Label>Отмена</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</WrapPanel>
```

Как видите, пиктограмма находится на разном расстоянии от начала... Пробовал разные конвейеры, но нужного эффекта я не смог добиться=(

Comment: Открыть в фотошопе эти 2 картинки и увидеть что эти картинки разные по размеру и, вероятнее всего, у второй картинки есть прозрачные отступы? Сделай что бы обе картинки были одинаковыми по размеру, тогда при одинаковых настройках верстки юая они будут выглядеть одинаково. И не нужно будет городить костылей вроди того который предложил Cruz21 в своем ответе

Comment: Я вам советую перейти на векторную графику, ибо картинки в WPF это зло. Картинки жрут места много, WPF их рендерит весьма криво (особенно мелкие), ну и ресайз, чуть растянули и у вас уже пошли артефакты.

Comment: Берите грид вместо StackPanel, ширину первой колонки делайте фиксированную, а ширину второй — все доступное пространство